# Brauche Deutsch-Unterstützung für mein Tastaturlayout (Dvorak)

Tags: support

Ich benutze eine spezielle Tastatur namens Dvorak in Debian. Es ist mühselig, Deutsch mithilfe von Copy-Pasting zu schreiben; ich brauche DeadKeys in Debian. Wie kann ich deutsche Sonderzeichen mit einer Tastatur schreiben? Ich habe auf anderen Seiten gesucht, aber kein Glück wie zum Beispiel [hier](https://superuser.com/questions/462510/dvorak-international-dead-keys-in-debian).

**Etwas Kurzes auf English**

> I am looking for some keyboard-layout to write German. I have some ideas:
>
> 1. DeadKeys -support (but misses things such as double SS)
> 2. Intelligent keyboard or software like on Android: if you type "Bucher", it will automatically change it to "Bücher" -- so can I get Germany -support just by installing some software without actually hacking the Xmodmap -things.
> 3. Can I get some sort of virtual keyboards to support German?

Answer (score 1):

Der CapsLock -Button verändert die Tastaturen und mit dem Dvorak-International

```
AltGr + , ---> ä 
AltGr + q ---> ö 
AltGr + y ---> ü 
AltGr + s ---> ß
```

so

> **1. Vorläufige Einstellungen**
>
> > $ setxkbmap -option grp:caps_toggle -variant dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys, us,de,no &
>
> **2. Dauernde Einstellungen**
>
> > `$ cat /etc/default/keyboard`
> >
> > ```
> > XKBMODEL="pc105"
> > XKBLAYOUT="us,de,no"
> > XKBVARIANT="dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys,"
> > XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle"
> > ```
>
> **3. Mehr [hier](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/6926/howto-spanish-keyboard-altgr-and-alt-keys-fix-on-laptops/).**

**Alert and Todos**

> > I. There is a mistake if you want to have many keyboard layouts. I cannot get it working with more than 3 keyboards such as:
> >
> > > $ setxkbmap -option grp:caps_toggle,grp:shifts_toggle,grp_led:scroll -variant
> > >       dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys,nodeadkeys, us,de,fi,no &
> >
> > II. find a command by which you can restart HAL or the XKB -thing, the above thread mentioned `"# /etc/init.d/hal restart"` but not working
> >     in my Debian Squeeze.
> >
> > III. The keyboard layout does not get loaded after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn du nicht davor zurückschreckst, ein neues Layout zu lernen: Verwende das [Neo-Tastatur-Layout](http://www.neo-layout.org/), welches für Deutsch und Englisch optimiert ist. Ich verwende es und bin sehr zufrieden.